# VS code terminal cannot execute task for deleting a folder on windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal, task, rmdir

I'm trying to delete a folder from a VS code task that will run a shell command.
My task looks like this:

```
        {
        "label": "Delete destination Folder",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "rd",
        "args": [
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\<PATH TO MY FOLDER> ",
            "/S",
            "/Q"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent",
            "panel": "new"
        }
```

When i try to run the task i get this error (i'm translating the error message, so it might not be perfect):

```
 Impossible to find a positional arguments that accepts '/S'.
 In row:1 char:1
+ rd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2\htdocs\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Does the terminal see RD like a command with a single argument?
Do i have to specify another field of the task?

Comment: This appears to be running under `PowerShell` and not `cmd`. In PowerShell, use the command `help Remove-Item -Full` for information about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, after looking at Remove-item API for powershell I managed to make it work in just 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be usefuel for somebody, i did it running `Remove-item`, not `rd`
(Thanks to [lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) who provided the answer):

```
        {
        "label": "Delete destination Folder",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "Remove-item",
        "args": [
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2\\htdocs\\webapps\\FEmatrixovaiole",
            "-recurse"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent",
            "panel": "new"
        }
```